# contextInitialized() method in ServletContextListener interface reject connect to DataBase

Tags: java, servletcontextlistener

why i have the following exception ((java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.13:1521:orcl)) when i connect to my DB using ServletContextListener
My code like that:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    System.out.println("i'm initilize ServletContextListener");
    try {
//          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.­OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.13:1521:orcl", "hr", "hr");
        System.out.println("schema name are: "+con.getSchema());
        //storing connection object as an attribute in ServletContext  
        ServletContext ctx = event.getServletContext();
        ctx.setAttribute("mycon", con);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("i have exception in _030MyListener-listener");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is your `class.forName` method commented?

Comment: thanks.. for your reply: but commenting it or not it's not responsible for that exception. but after i found solution class.forName must found in my code

Answer (score 0):

i search for many hours for solution which are simply : enlarge memory setting for Tomcat to load driver. and at same-time use class.forName method to start creating your oracle-driver. i don't know why use class.forName although i already have DriverManager class. but fine